# Query to update primary key column values

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2

I have a database table in `DB2` which has three `primary key` columns and all are of type - `VARCHAR`.

Now, these column values are editable via a screen in Application UI. My question is about which approach is better,

1. `UPDATE` query with old primary key column values in `WHERE` clause

   OR
2. `DELETE` old record first ( with old primary key column values in `WHERE` clause ) and then `INSERT` all the data from UI as a fresh record.

In UI, its mandatory to provide `Primary Key Column` values (by default - old values) but its optional that user will provide new values.

Comment: No matter what approach you take, make sure you account for other tables having foreign key references, and duplicate records.

Comment: I agree Dan Bracuk, but if you take the solution 2 dont forget to do this into transaction, if delete work but not insert you lose your date. With transaction you can rollback if error. Note: for use transaction your tables must have journalized

Comment: It would be best to use a single-column surrogate key (sequence / UUID) instead of a composite business key. This would make updates much more simple when you don't have to worry about updating foreign keys in other tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. An `update` statement will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I recently saw approach#2 being taken in two apps so I thought it might be done for some reason but unfortunately there was no body in those teams to clarify me so I asked here.